# Transforming Fixed-Length to XML in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to transform an fixed-length file to XML in XSLT v2.0. I saw other references but I can't apply in my XSLT. If for example, I have a text file like this:

```
UHL1 2016-999999    000000001 DAILY  001                                                            
ITNCC609890989099ITNCC463374755000010000.00   SANTANDER CONSUMERBOA-t-1111111111  Bank of America    2016-
ITNCC463374755017ITNCC463374755000010000.00                     CONTRA            SANTANDER CONSUMER 2016-
UTL110000.00     10000.00     00000010000001
```

The 1st line with UHL is a Header Record, the 2nd line is a Detail1 Record, 3rd line is a Detail2 Record and the last line is a Trailer Record.

I need to generate an XML file like this:

```
<BACSRecord>
<Header>
    <Item1>UHL</Item1>
    <Item2>1</Item2>
    <Item3/>
    <Item4>2016-</Item4>
    <Item5>999999</Item5>
    <Item6/>
    <Item7>00</Item7>
    <Item8>000000</Item8>
    <Item9>1 DAILY  </Item9>
    <Item10>001</Item10>
    <Item11/>
    <Item12/>
    <Item13/>
    <Item14/>
</Header>
<Transaction>
    <Detail1>
        <Item1>ITNCC6</Item1>
        <Item2>09890989</Item2>
        <Item3>0</Item3>
        <Item4>99</Item4>
        <Item5>ITNCC4</Item5>
        <Item6>63374755</Item6>
        <Item7>0000</Item7>
        <Item8>10000.00   </Item8>
        <Item9>SANTANDER CONSUMER</Item9>
        <Item10>BOA-t-1111111111  </Item10>
        <Item11>Bank of America   </Item11>
        <Item12> 2016-</Item12>
    </Detail1>
    <Detail2>
        <Item1>ITNCC4</Item1>
        <Item2>63374755</Item2>
        <Item3>0</Item3>
        <Item4>17</Item4>
        <Item5>ITNCC4</Item5>
        <Item6>63374755</Item6>
        <Item7>0000</Item7>
        <Item8>10000.00   </Item8>
        <Item9/>
        <Item10>CONTRA</Item10>
        <Item11/>
        <Item12>SANTANDER CONSUMER</Item12>
        <Item13> 2016-</Item13>
    </Detail2>
</Transaction>
<Trailer>
    <Item1>UTL</Item1>
    <Item2>1</Item2>
    <Item3>10000.00     </Item3>
    <Item4>10000.00     </Item4>
    <Item5>0000001</Item5>
    <Item6>0000001</Item6>
    <Item7/>
    <Item8/>
</Trailer>
```

Is it possible to do it in XSLT?

Thank you.

Comment: Typically XSLT would be used to transform XML to text, and not the other way around. However, it is possible to do this in XSLT 2.0 by means of the "unparsed-text" function. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unparsed-text.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
 <BACSRecord>
  <xsl:variable name="lines" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('data.txt'), '\n')">
   <Header>
    <xsl:sequence select="f:header($lines[1])"/>
   </Header>
   <Transaction>
    <xsl:for-each select="subsequence($lines, 2)">
     <xsl:element name="Details{position()}">
      <xsl:sequence select="f:details(.)"/>
     </xsl:element>
   </Transaction>
   <Trailer>
    <xsl:sequence select="f:trailer($lines[last()])"/>
   </Header>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="f:details" as="element(*)">
 <xsl:param name="line" as="xs:string"/>
 <xsl:sequence select="f:split(., (6,8,1,2,6,8,4,....))"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="f:split" as="element(*)">
  <xsl:param name="line" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="widths as="xs:integer*"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($widths)">
   <xsl:element name="Item{.}">
    <xsl:value-of select="subtring($line, sum(subsequence($widths, 1, .-1)), $widths[current()]"/>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```